# How to do batch processing in Pro*c

Tags: c, proc

`enter code here`I want to do batch processing using host array in pro c. But when the records are not equal to array length*n (n is 1 ,2 ,3 ...) then my program is failed to fetched row.

I dont know how to fetch remaining records.
 `int empid[20];
 my table contains 24 records.
so after 1st fetch its showing error.`
    void print_rows(n)
    int n;
    {
        int i;

```
    printf("\nNumber  Employee  Salary");
    printf("\n------  --------  -------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d    %s  %8.2f\n", emp_rec.emp_number[i],
           emp_rec.emp_name[i], emp_rec.salary[i]);

}  

void  main()
{
    int  num_ret;               /* number of rows returned */


    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO sql_error("Oracle error:");
/* Declare a cursor for the FETCH. */
    EXEC SQL DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT empno, ename, sal FROM emp;

    EXEC SQL OPEN c1;

/* Initialize the number of rows. */
num_ret = 0;

/* Array fetch loop - ends when NOT FOUND becomes true. */
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;

for (;;)
{
    EXEC SQL FETCH c1 INTO :emp_rec;

/* Print however many rows were returned. */
    print_rows(sqlca.sqlerrd[2] - num_ret);
    num_ret = sqlca.sqlerrd[2];        /* Reset the number. */
}

/* Print remaining rows from last fetch, if any. */
if ((sqlca.sqlerrd[2] - num_ret) > 0)
    print_rows(sqlca.sqlerrd[2] - num_ret);

EXEC SQL CLOSE c1;

/* Disconnect from the database. */
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}`
```

`

Please help me how to fetch remaining records using pro c

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we can only guess at what the problem might be.  Are you not using a cursor to retrieve rows?

Comment: i have added my code .